# Structure of codebase to build for multiple platforms from one codebase in VuetifyJS/VueJS

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, electron, vuetify.js

I would like to use the [VuetifyJS/VueJS templates](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#new-applications) to build a **Web** app (PWA), **Android** app (Cordova) and **Desktop** app (Electron) from one codebase.
What is the best way to structure the main codebase to easily create the built for each platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you use Cordova you should place your build files in the dist folder, as you are used to. Then I do the following:

After Installing Cordova initialize in your project

```
cordova create mobile com.f1lt3r."${PWD##*/}"
cd mobile
```

Lets add the Android platform

```
cordova platform add android
```

This creates a mobile folder with the Cordova project in it. Next, create a symbolic link from your project build files to the Cordova web root.

```
cd ..
rm -rf mobile/www/*
ln -s $(pwd)/dist/* $(pwd)/mobile/www
```

Now, for Electron you could take a look at the config files of SimulatedGREG/electron-vue, I am not too familiar with this, but I think it would be possible to do something similar as with Cordova.